# can anyone tell me,what is the error in the program?This program is to get the file extension only

Tags: c++, string

the code for this program is

```
using namespace std;
std::vector<std::string> get_Extension(std::vector<std::string> arr)
{
    std::vector<string>v;
    string s;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;arr[i].at(j)!='.';j++);
        for(int j;j<arr[i].length();j++)
        {
            s+=arr[i].at(j);
        }
        v.push_back(s);
        s.clear();
    }
    return v;
}
```

can anyone tell me that,what is the error in this program?
It is a function that maps files to their extension names.
SEE THIS LINK TO KNOW WHAT IS THE AIM OF THIS FUNCTION:
https://edabit.com/challenge/yYEJXuYHHYpkRRoyW

Comment: [std::string::rfind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) may be useful here. Or, better still [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) if it is available.

Comment: What happens if the file does not contain an extension? What happens if it has multiple extensions? (`.tar.gz` files come to mind)

Comment: Problem is that it isn't program. It is single function. And even that does not compile because `#include`s are missing.

Comment: If you ask what's wrong you should add a description of expected and actual beahviour. But I suspect it has to do with the useless `for(int j=0;arr[i].at(j)!='.';j++);` and the unitialized `j` in the following loop.

Comment: Instead of writing one function that odes this to an entire vector, write a function that does this to one path, and then use that function to transform each vector element.

Comment: see the link given in question to know what is the aim of this function.@churill

Answer (score 1):

First of

```
for(int j=0;arr[i].at(j)!='.';j++);
```

is a loop that does nothing. It doesn't modify any variables outside the loop and it doesn't have a body to do anything.

In the next line

```
for(int j;j<arr[i].length();j++)
```

You you have new `j` (it's not the same as above!) which is no initialized and so has a random value. To repair this specific code you should move `j` out of the two loops.

An easier solution would be to use [std::string::rfind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) and substr.

```
std::string fileName = "...";
size_t extStart = fileName.rfind('.');
std::string extension = filename.substr(extStart); // including the .
```

or if you can use c++17 (or later) you could use [std::filesystem::path::extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension):

```
std::sting extension = std::filesystem::path(fileName).extension(); //alos including the .
```

Comment: The first `for` loop gets the index of the dot

Comment: @acraig5075 But doesn't store it anywhere, so it's useless.

Comment: Because the bug is that `j` is shadowed. See my answer.

Comment: @acraig5075 I know. I described the code as given, where the loop is useless.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `j` in both `for` loops, you are in fact [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `j`.

What you want is to declare `j` outside of the `for` loops:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; arr[i].at(j) != '.'; j++); // get the index of the dot
for (     ; j < arr[i].length(); j++) // iterate the chars of extension
{ ... }
```

That said, you are doing no error checking for when the strings don't contain the dot and you will then get bad things happening.

Comment: IT IS FOR:for example::  get_Extension(["code.html", "code.css"])
➞ ["html", "css"]

get_Extension(["project1.jpg", "project1.pdf", "project1.mp3"])
➞ ["jpg", "pdf", "mp3"]

get_Extension(["ruby.rb", "cplusplus.cpp", "python.py", "javascript.js"])
➞ ["rb", "cpp", "py", "js"]

Comment: @AmitNandal And that is what I've answered ??? Your program almost works, and I've told you what was wrong.

Comment: @acraig5075 Although your fix is correct, the second `j` doesn't actually ***shadow*** the first one because the first `j` goes out of scope when its `for` loop ends.